# jquery - show/hide elements + control individual time for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show and hide elements, sort of like a slideshow, but I want to control how long each individual element is shown for. I don't want the elements to fade in or out either, but just appear immediately after the previous element has been hidden. Try to picture credits after a tv show or something like that, but each element can be individually timed. How can I achieve this with what I have so far?

(I'm having trouble using .delay - it's not doing what I've told it to do in the js)

```
<html>
<title>Untitled</title>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#one').delay(1000).show(0, function() { });

    $('#one').delay(3000).hide(0, function() { });

    $('#two').delay(3000).show(0, function() { });

    $('#two').delay(4000).hide(0, function() { });

    $('#three').delay(4000).show(0, function() { });

    $('#three').delay(6000).hide(0, function() { });

    $('#four').delay(6000).show(0, function() { });

    $('#four').delay(6000).hide(0, function() { });

});

</script>   
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

    body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    }

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
    color: #111;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>              
    <p id="one">this is text #1</p>
    <p id="two">this is text #2</p>
    <p id="three">this is text #3</p>
    <p id="four">this is text #4</p>
    <p id="five">this is text #5</p>
    <p id="six">this is text #6</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to guess at exactly what you wanted, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$('#one').delay(1000).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);
$('#two').delay(2000).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);
$('#three').delay(3000).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);
$('#four').delay(4000).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);
$('#five').delay(5000).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);
$('#six').delay(6000).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0);
```

You can see it working at http://jsfiddle.net/3XnGR/